# Integrating Wordpress with Existing PhP site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an existing php site and i have tried using wpinclude plugin of wordpress to integrate both of them but in vain i havent got anything. I want to integrate all the functionality of the site into wordpress except the presentation

Comment: With the amount of information on the PHP app to be integrated, this is hard to answer. If your application has some open api you might develop a plugin for WP. Or even use jQuery to get data from the PHP app.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Wordpress functions in youre existing site by includen the wp-load file:

```
<?php require( '../my_wordpress_install_root/wp-load.php' ); ?>
```

But if you work the other way arround thus through Wordpress. You can create a Plugin which talks to youre functions in the existing site.